# Remove 2 connections HttpWebRequest limitation in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem accessing a website via http 1.1 using HttpWebRequest class. The request works only first two times when I start the application, and than times out.

Apparently this is all about that 2 concurrent connections limitation.

So first of all, how can I remove that with code, or changing manifest?
Second, how to force the use of http 1.0?
And third, that's my code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
req.CookieContainer = Memory._Jar;

req.Method = "GET";
req.Host = url.Split(new string[] { "//" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('/')[0];
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
req.UserAgent = Memory._UserAgent;
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
req.Proxy = Memory._Proxy;
req.Timeout = Memory._Timeout;

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

I don't use concurent threads, I don't even set "keep alive" and the website is not https, so I imagine the request and response objects get garbage collected when they run out of scope, and that's all about it (they don't implement IDisposible), but obviously that's not the case...

So what connection is being made? How it's persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default connection limit is 2. You can change it from config file or code level.

Config:

```
 <connectionManagement>
      <clear/>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
    </connectionManagement>
```

Code :

System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;

Comment: Where this code goes, and my project is a dll, can I change the config on the dll?

Comment: If you want to change inside config. Just add in your config file of your main project. OR just add one line of code in your DLL.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the connection on the response object:

```
resp.Close();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.close

Comment: Sh*t that's embarrassing, thank you verry much, solved my problem